# Jetty, force webapp to use different javax.mail from that one included in server lib/jndi

Tags: java, jetty, jakarta-mail, jetty-9

I'm quite newbie in Jetty, I've used Tomcat for many years, I would like to know the best practice to force my webapp to use javax.mail 1.5.5 since it is using javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar found on /srv/jetty/lib/jndi of jetty 9.3.10.

I don't believe it is safe replace that version with that one wanted by my webapplication, is it true?

At last if the best practice was to update the jar leaving it where it is, then should I remove that dependency from my webapp, in a way that in WEB-INF/lib it shouldn't be present?

Really thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Jetty but you can probably just replace the jar file.

If you want to use a version of JavaMail bundled with your app instead of the one in the Jetty installation, there might be a way to tell Jetty to prefer your version.

Note that the [current version of JavaMail is 1.5.6](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/) so I don't know why you would want to use 1.5.5.

Comment: In most recent jetty releases there is an older version of javamail bundled in that javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar, for example the FetchProfile class have no SIZE field.... 
I don't know which version is but I don't care of it, I just don't want to use it.

Jetty classloader, load javax packages from its lib, giving them higher priority than webapp/lib

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there is no mechanism to force a servlet container like jetty to use the bundled mail-jar from your war file.

If You do not need the jetty jndi - mail - feature, documented [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JNDI#Configuring_Mail) just get rid of the jar.

Interestingly Java Mail FAQ points this out regarding tomcat:

> Q: How do I configure Tomcat to allow me to use JavaMail in my web
>   application?  A: To run a web application using JavaMail, you can add
>   the JavaMail javax.mail.jar file and, if you're not using JDK 1.6 or
>   newer, the JavaBeans Activation Framework javax.activation.jar file to
>   the lib directory under the directory in which you installed Tomcat.
>   This will cause Tomcat to include these jar files in its classpath
>   automatically. For details, see JNDI Resources HOW-TO in the Tomcat
>   documentation. Alternatively, you can package the mail.jar file and
>   activation.jar files in the lib directory of your web application
>   package (war file).

So Java Mail points falsely out that you just need to bundle it with your war file.

Also from the FAQ

> If you're running in a web server or application server, it may be
>   providing its own version of mail.jar in one of its directories. You
>   should only have one version of mail.jar available to your
>   application.

https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ

Comment: Such a mechanism exists, please read the full thread in jetty-users https://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/jetty-users/msg07753.html
I've answered with that link but some stackoverflow admin has deleted it...

Comment: Unfortunately now I need to configure mail/Session jndi too, so in summary I need either jndi resource or using directly javamail api in my code, and I need latest javamail 1.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I've received help from jetty-users, where contributor Jan Bartel said me:

> I'd probably make a fresh jndi.mod, called eg my-jndi.mod that is
>   copied from $JETTY_HOME/modules/jndi.mod and put it into
>   $JETTY_BASE/modules. Then I'd change the last line of it to refer to a
>   different lib, eg lib/my-jndi. So the module would look like this:
>
> [name] myjndi
>
> [depend] server
>
> [lib] lib/jetty-jndi-${jetty.version}.jar lib/my-jndi/*.jar Put the
>   javax.mail jars and any others you need into $JETTY_BASE/lib/my-jndi.
>   Then all you need to do is to activate it with a java -jar
>   ../start.jar --add-to-start=my-jndi and you're done. The good thing
>   about this approach is that it is portable across any updates to
>   different versions of jetty.

It was furthermore opened an [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/1597)